# Android SQLite3 problem enforcing primary key

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, primary-key

I have a listview with a custom adapter that uses an sql cursor.  When I add items to my listview, the item will be added to my sqlite3 database and the listview will refresh.

My one problem is that I am able to add duplicate items, and I do not want my application to allow duplicates to be added.

I have added a primary key to my database (on itemNumber), however the database does not seem to be enforcing this.  Here is how I create my database:

```
private static final String DB_CREATE_MASTER = "CREATE TABLE "
            + "MyTable"
            + " (_id INTEGER, itemNumber TEXT,"
            + "itemPlace TEXT," + "itemTimeTEXT,"
            + "itemCode INTEGER,"
            + "dbdatestamp TEXT" + "PRIMARY KEY(itemNumber)" +");";
```

Does anyone know why I am able to add more than 1 duplicate itemNumber to my listview?

Thanks!

---

EDIT:

```
private static final String DB_CREATE_MASTER = "CREATE TABLE "
            + "MyTable"
            + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, itemNumber TEXT,"
            + "itemPlace TEXT," + "itemTimeTEXT,"
            + "itemCode INTEGER,"
            + "dbdatestamp TEXT" + "UNIQUE(itemNumber)" +");";
```

EDIT:

---

This is how I add the itemNumber to the database:

```
values.put("itemNumber", myClass.itemNumber);
values.put("itemName", myClass.itemName);
values.put("itemTime", myClass.itemTime);
values.put("dbdatestamp", "03/01/1960 08:55");
this.db.insert(MY_TABLE, null, values);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary key consists of 2 fields: _id and itemNumber. That means that a duplicate itemNumber is not enough to enforce the constraint. A duplicate would be an item with the same _id AND itemNumber. You could change the CREATE statement like this

```
PRIMARY KEY(_id), UNIQUE(itemNumber)
```

The UNIQUE constraint wouldn't allow duplicate item numbers.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to include _id in the Primary Key in my posted code. I am still able to add duplicate values when I remove _id as a Primary Key OR if i make item number unique...See update above..

Comment: How do you generate item numbers? Are you sure that you have duplicates?

Comment: The numbers are returned from a web service. If you look at my second edit above, you can see how I add the number to the database. In the method that does the above, I added a print statement to show me what the itemNumber is, and that shows 100% that they are duplicates...

Comment: When I view the schema for the table, it does not show itemNumber as being UNIQUE...

Comment: Hmm, that seems strange. I'm running out of ideas. I guess you could just check if there's already an itemNumber before you insert a new item but that's not a good solution.